# Search table for a particular text and click on the second cell of the same row in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

[click to see Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Ak9.png)

Hi guys,
So basically i need to search for In progress applications and click on the application id. Below is the HTML.

```html
Html: emphasized text
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="list">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="headerRow">
      <th scope="col" class="actionColumn">Action</th>
      <th class="zen-deemphasize" scope="col">Application ID</th>
      <th class="zen-deemphasize" scope="col">Application Status</th>
      <th class=" zen-deemphasize" scope="col">Co-Applicant</th>
      <th class="DateElement zen-deemphasize" scope="col">Created Date</th>
      <th class=" zen-deemphasize" scope="col">Created By</th>
      <th class="DateElement zen-deemphasize" scope="col">Last Modified Date</th>
      <th class=" zen-deemphasize" scope="col">Last Modified By</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- ListRow -->
    <tr onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" class="dataRow even first">
      <td class="actionColumn"><a title="Edit - Record 1 - 27394022" class="actionLink" href="/a08Q00000071tCE/e?retURL=%2F001Q0000012jqbt">Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a title="Delete - Record 1 - 27394022" onclick="return confirmDelete();" class="actionLink" href="/setup/own/deleteredirect.jsp?delID=a08Q00000071tCE&amp;retURL=%2F001Q0000012jqbt&amp;_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN=VmpFPSxNakF4Tnkwd05DMHlNbFF4TURveE1Ub3pOeTR4TmpWYSxSTHpOd1ZjSC1CUmZfc3puYllINktsLFltVXpPVFUy">Del</a></td>
      <th
        class=" dataCell  " scope="row"><a href="/a08Q00000071tCE">27394022</a></th>
        <td class=" dataCell  ">In Progress</td>
        <td class=" dataCell  ">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class=" dataCell  DateElement">17/04/2017</td>
        <td class=" dataCell  "><a href="/005E0000005pAqf">Web API</a>, 17/04/2017 5:54 AM</td>
        <td class=" dataCell  DateElement">17/04/2017</td>
        <td class=" dataCell  "><a href="/005E0000005pAqf">Web API</a>, 17/04/2017 6:17 AM</td>
    </tr>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, Mehek. Please read the help on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular, show what you've already tried and tell us what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following xpath to click on id based on the status 'In Progress' you have

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//table[@class='list']//td[normalize-space()='In Progress']/preceding-sibling::th/a")).click();
```

Note : If you have same element more then one the use the`List` to get and iterate all those

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("the css selector for all the elements in the table"));
for(WebElement e : elements){
    if(e.getText().contains("In progress")){               
        WebElement elmt = e.findElement(By.cssSelector("the css selector for the id"));
        elmt.click();
    }
}
```

you can use the cssSelector or others selectors (id/xpath..)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below xpath:

//th[text()='In Progress']/preceding-sibling::th[1]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It didnt work. it says unable to locate the element

Comment: Is your inprogess tag enclosed in td? If yes please change it acoordingly

Answer (score -1):

```
    // Get table headers first
    List<WebElement> tblHeaders = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//table/tbody/tr[@class='headerRow']/th"));
    int applicationId = 0;
    int applicaitonStatus = 0;
    // Get column numbers for Application Id, Application Status columns
    for (int colCount = 0; colCount < tblHeaders.size(); colCount++) {
        if ("Application Status".equals(tblHeaders.get(colCount).getText())) {
            applicaitonStatus = colCount;
        } else if ("Application Id".equals(tblHeaders.get(colCount)
                .getText())) {
            applicationId = colCount;
        }
    }

    // Get table rows
    List<WebElement> tblRows = driver.findElements(By
            .xpath(".//table/tbody/tr[contains(@class,'dataRow')]"));

    for (WebElement webElement : tblRows) {
        List<WebElement> tblCells = webElement.findElements(By
                .tagName("td"));
        // If Application status is In Progress
        if ("In Progress".equals(tblCells.get(applicaitonStatus).getText())) {
            //Click respective Application Id
            tblCells.get(applicationId).click();
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to answer my question. But i am getting the following error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 20, Size: 6 on the following line :     if ("In Progress".equals(tblCells.get(applicaitonStatus).getText())) {

Comment: Code only answers are not allowed on SO. Please take a minute to summarize what your code does and how it answers the question.

Comment: Mehek, Identify the table uniquely. May be the page has multiple tables and the tblHeaders list is capturing all the headers. The size of tblHeaders should be 6 only.